# Is there a way to somehow extract an int[ ] array value from a method that returns a void?

Tags: java, arrays, return-value, void, return-type

If I have the following code that modifies a created array and returns only a **void**:

```
 public static void modifyArray()
{
      myFunction(createArray(1));
}
```

Where  `createArray()` is just some function that generates an array as follows:

```
 public static int[] createArray(int n)
 {
      //Lines of code that generate an array;
 }
```

And `myFunction()` is just some arbitrary function that modifies an array and returns it as a void:

```
 public static void myFunction(int[] anArray)
 {
      //Lines of codes that modifies any int[] array passed to this function;
 }
```

How can I get back the modified array in the `modifyArray()` function as an **int[ ]** using another function, WITHOUT changing the return type of `myFunction()` to an int[], such as:

```
    public static int[] convertModifiedArray()
    {
           return modifyArray(); //This is an error since modifyArray() is a void, not an int[].  I just don't know a way to somehow "translate" a void into an int[] and I need help with this part.
    }
```

Comment: sorry, the `anArray()` was a typo.  It should be `createArray()`

Comment: Don't fix typos with comments, [edit] your post.

Comment: Working on the input parameter doesn't seem to be a safe way. Moreover, if you use a global class variable, you won't be able to use your class from different places as your global variable will be shared

Comment: Void is actually not a data type (object or primitive).  An array is an object and you are passing the value of the reference of the object or the value of the primitive.  You need to change your `modifyArray` method to return the array.  How else will you code know what the reference to the array is?

Comment: You are missing some information, s there a difference if you call multiple time the same function ( with the same parameter) ? Use a Map to store the array identify by the `int n`, you will be able to get it with a getter. How course, this will still limit you to one array per parameter value. `returns it as a void`, no you don't return anything with a `void`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either you can change the return type to int[]
Or you can create a global variable and set the value in that, in the method.

Answer (score 1):

You can declare a instance variable like int[] myArray in your class. In modifyArray function you can assign myArray to modified array. You will get modified array in myArray and no need to change return type of method.

Comment: Watch out, these are `static method`.

Answer (score -2):

```
public static void modifyArray() {
    int[] a = createArray(1);
    myFunction(a);
    // Whatever you want to do with a
}
```

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question.

Comment: Sorry... I'll use my words next time :)